# How to force view updates in angularjs by services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hold a global `MainCtrl` controller that serves the navigation menus. From time to time these menu items should be updated by various controllers.

Now I thought I might just bind the navigation links to the controller, and update the controller variable as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="nav in navigations">
        <a href="#{{nav.path}}">{{nav.label}}</a>
    </li>
</div>
<div ng-view></div> <!-- renders different controllers, eg testController.js -->

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'navigationService', function($scope, navigationService) {
    //binding the property of the service
    $scope.navigations = navigationService.navigations;
}]);

app.service('navigationService', function() {
    return {
        navigations: null
    };
});
```

But, when calling the service and updating the `navigations` variable inside, nothing is changed in the view. Why?

```
angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', 'navigationService', function($scope, $http, navigationService) {
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            navigationService.navigations = data.some.navigations; //assume json data exists
        });
}]);
```

How can I achieve this two-way databinding, forcing a view update from one controller to another?

Comment: You can use $rootScope instead of $scope.

Comment: It's that kind of abusing the rootScope, and it's cleaner using a service?

Comment: What happens when you create an arbitrary object like $scope.nav and then bind to the service with $scope.nav.navigations = navigationService.navigations?

Comment: This did not change anything. (`<li ng-repeat="nav in navs,navigations">` and in controller: `$scope.navs = []; $scope.navs.navigations = navService.navigations;` )

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `primitive` from service. A primitive doesn't have inheritance.

Return an object instead:

```
app.service('navigationService', function() {    
    var nav ={}; // object that will be returned       
    function init(){
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data) {
                // modify object returned from service rather than reassign a primitive value
                nav.items = data.some.navigations; exists
            });
    }

    init();//make request to load the data

    return { // can add more properties if needed           
        nav: nav
    };
});
```

Then in controller:

```
 $scope.navigations = navigationService.nav;
 // will initially be {} and later will inherit items property
```

In view

```
<div ng-repeat="item in navigations.items">
```

angular internal watches will pick up the changes now made to the object and render view accordingly

Comment: I find this answer clever, but, could you elaborate on the advantage of using it (having to return the same object reference) over adding the 'primitive' to the watch list ? having just 1 watch instead of 2 (+ the one in ngRepeat). Also, I think it is wrong to say "inherit", here you are just sharing the same reference between objects. (updating one, means updating the two). Anyway good answer, I can add +1 vote.

Comment: @MoncefHassein-bey the inheritance regarding primitives meaning that `var a="foo"; b=a; a="bar"` ... `b` is still `"foo"` . Yes regarding object, is same reference which is what prototypal inheritance is all about. A change made to a reference anywhere in the app will be made in all references. Also note that in another question OP was tring to share this data across multiple controllers

Comment: As for 2 watches... I only see one this way (ng-repeat)...no other one in controller as other answers are doing

Comment: What I mean is that there a diffrence between using javascript inheritance like 1. var anotherMe = Object.create(me.prototype); and 1. var anotherMe = me; the first statement they will have shared .prototype object (inheretence) , and, anotherMe !== me, but the second statement we are sharing the hole same reference anotherMe point to an object and me point to the same. do you think they are the same ?

Answer (score 2):

After using Angular for more than 2 years, I discovered, whenever you want that functionality with multiple binding from different services/controllers/directives, ALWAYS use json property, and NEVER ovverride variable instance:

I would replace that:

```
$scope.navigations = navigationService.navigations;
```

with that:

```
var state = {
   navigations: []
};
$scope.state = state;

state.navigations = navigationService.navigations;  // i prefer such syntax
// or
$scope.state.navigations = navigationService.navigations;
```

Why?  Probably because of Angular automatic $watch()/$watchCollection() functions, which are bind to variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $rootscope and broadcast to and keep eye on broadcast

Say your data is changed from x controller, so here you can broadcast like this

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('menu-need-to-refresh');
```

In your main controller keep eye, like this

```
$scope.$on('menu-need-to-refresh', function (event, data) {
    $scope.menus= service.newMenu();
});
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Update** : @charlietfl + @Dmitri Algazin method is more elegant as it takes advantage of javascript itself, by using references, and avoid using two watchers in controller + ngRepeat (watchCollection in this directive will do the work).

**My original answer :**

You should watch for changes in the service from `MainCtrl` using `$scope.$watch` :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'navigationService', function($scope, navigationService) {
    //binding the property of the service
    $scope.$watch(
        function(){
            return navigationService.navigations;
        }
    , function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue !== oldValue){
            $scope.navigations = newValue;
        }
    })

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem simply by using [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

ex: 
`$scope.$watch(
     function(){return navigationService.navigations;},
     function(newVal, oldVal){$scope.navigations = newVal;}
)`

this code is not tested, but you get the gist

Comment: $scope.$watch is bad practice to use... you can get same effect if you read my post above...